# What purpose do the extra wires for my boiler thermostat serve?

Tags: wiring, boiler, water-circulating-heating

I am pulling out an existing wood burning boiler, EKO Biomass 40, and replacing it with a Switzer boiler. This boiler will be my primary and I have a secondary oil-burner in my basement. The heating system is run with a Tekmar 401.

When I did the original install, I ran thermostat wire from the Tekmar to the 3rd and 4th terminals on the EKO (in left part of picture). What purpose do they serve? I need to figure out where to attach them on the new boiler.

[image: Tekmar]

[image: EKO]
Thank you for your help.